# How to pass foreach inside laravel DB::select query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to iterate through list of words broken down in a function processNeedle. This is working fine with ordinary php but not in laravel.

```
    $query = $request->input('query');  

    $trim = new SearchTrim();

    $words = $trim->ProcessNeedle($query);


    $concat = "CONCAT(";        

     $concat.="title,";

    $concat.="'')";


    $sql =DB::select("SELECT DISTINCT id,title,code,abstract FROM projects WHERE 0 ";

    foreach ($words as $word) $sql.=" OR $concat LIKE '%$word%'";
    $sql.=" ORDER BY id DESC";
```

My query function well like this in php

```
SQL query: SELECT DISTINCT id,title,code FROM projects WHERE 0 OR CONCAT(title,'') LIKE '%intranet%' OR CONCAT(title,'') LIKE '%mailing%' ORDER BY id DESC;
```

How do i achieve this in Laravel Please help

Comment: Don't query like that, it will cause sql-injection

Comment: Okkk.. But how do I achieve this in laravel? iterating the words from array along with the concat statement

Comment: why do u concat title with empty string `''` and why `where 0`?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT id,title,code FROM projects WHERE 0 OR CONCAT(title,'') LIKE '%intranet%' OR CONCAT(title,'') LIKE '%mailing%' ORDER BY id DESC;

Comment: This query works perfectly in ordinary php... Its only in laravel its not working..

Comment: if the sql result is what u want, i think you need to remove 0, and if the title's type is string. I think u don't need to use `concat` with string

Comment: Like this: `SELECT DISTINCT id,title,code FROM projects WHERE title LIKE '%intranet%' OR title LIKE '%mailing%' ORDER BY id DESC;`

Comment: Remove `DB::select` and just leave `$sql = "SELECT..."`. After foreach loop and fully formed `$sql` string, then go with `DB::select($sql)`.

Comment: That was really cool man.. Thank you. I wonder why my head did not go there.. May be I'm tired,, I need to rest.... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example . i hope it helps you .

Pass foreach inside laravel DB::select query

```html
$items = ['condition1', 'condition2', 'condition3'];
        $results = App\Model::where(function ($query) use ($items) {
            foreach($items as $item) {
                $query->orWhere('dbfield', 'LIKE', "%$item%");
            }
        })
            ->get();
        dd($results);
```

Comment: Hello, Please how do I edit this query to display the row that have the highest words first